# How to see Node method path/file

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux

I see several node module js files scattered through node_modules directories in my computer.

How can I see the path taken to execute http.request (or any other method).

I want to see the code for the methods I am calling (where it lives on my computer).

Also wondering if the code executed when I call a method in node is JS, binary, or both.

Comment: Where does the `http` in your question come from?

Comment: @GOTO0 It's a node module installed with `npm install -g http`. Just an example. I am wondering how I can see the path of any method I call without having to explicitly use the path (and that does not just happen to be in my current directory)

Comment: So you are importing it with `const http = require("http");`? Sorry, this is not obvious to any of us...

Comment: @GOTO0 No... I just ran `npm install -g http` in terminal. Then in node.. I can, for example, type `http.request.toString()` and the output is code... So Node certainly has found the method http.request - I want to know WHERE I can see this code in my file system. Just looking for http module in one of the node_modules directories is not straight forward

Comment: That's the built-in [http](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http) module of Node.js, not a globally installed package. You can find the source code [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v17.2.0/lib/http.js#L95-L97).

Comment: @GOTO0 is the built-in http module something distinct from what I installed with `npm install -g http`?

Comment: Yes. Though, I'm not sure what it is that gets installed by `npm`. It seems that the package name is a placeholder: https://www.npmjs.com/package/http

Comment: @GOTO0 okay i was wondering about about the place holder looking stuffs when examining files. fs package has same thing. Maybe these names used to hold http and fs before they became built-ins...